# Mixed integer linear programming - making a variable have influence on another variable only when it is equal to zero

Tags: integer-programming

Having an integer variable $D \in \{-k,-k+1,...,-1,0,1,...,k-1,k\}$, how do I make it affect another variable only when $D = 0$?

Specifically, I have a binary variable $U$ in my model. I want it to be set to $1$ when $D = 0$, but leave it free in other cases.

What constraint or constraints can I add in order to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

This is not so easy with a variable $D$ that can be positive and negative. We could do:
$$
  U + |D| \ge 1
$$

To linearize this we can use a variable splitting technique. Something like:
$$\begin{align}
 &D_{plus} \ge 0 \\
 &D_{min} \ge 0 \\
 &D = D_{plus}-D_{min} \\
 &D_{abs} = D_{plus}+D_{min} \\
 &D_{plus} \le k \delta \\
 &D_{min} \le k (1-\delta) \\
 & \delta \in \{0,1\}\\
 & U \in \{0,1\}\\
 &U + D_{abs} \ge 1 
\end{align}$$